# Issues with getting VoiceChannel.members and Guild.members to return a full list

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Any time I try to use VoiceChannel.members or Guild.members it does not give me a full list of applicable members. I'm grabbing both the VoiceChannel and the Guild from the context in a text command like this:

```
@bot.command(name='followme')
async def follow_me(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice != None:
        guild = ctx.guild
        tracking = ctx.author
        channel = tracking.voice.channel
```

Later on I've tried to use the channel like this:

```
for member in channel.members:
            if member.voice.mute != True:
                await member.edit(mute=True)
```

However, it's only finding my user despite having another user in the channel.

I found that the only way I could get an accurate representation of members in the channel is using:

```
channel.voice_states.keys()
```

Using voice_states, I can get an accurate list of members, but only by their IDs when I still need to manipulate the member itself.
So I tried this:

```
for key in channel.voice_states.keys():
            member = guild.get_member(key)
            if member.voice.mute != True:
                await member.edit(mute=True)
```

However, the guild isn't pulling the right set of users and despite verifying all the IDs were correct, guild.members is *also* not working appropriately.

Any input on how to get this working properly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of October 7th, Discord has changed their API to require bots to declare [gateway intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#intents-primer).  Make sure your discord.py is updated to at least version 1.5 and enable the members intent:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```